# OutputCache at "Static" ASPX file has any advantage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, caching, outputcache

I have some ASPX files with no code, I just need ASPX because of Masters Pages, and reuse some static ascx files.

I will have some gain if I put OutputCache directive at my pages?

It is a HotSite and will have one million page views at the peak.

I also have some pages with dynamic texts, with Login name, I am thinking to use asp:Substitution control, it is a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will probably give you a benefit of not loading your file from the disk as the whole output will be kept in memory. You are also skipping a part of page life cycle which will save a few CPU ticks.

It the page is static you might want to cache it on the client so no request will come to your server from that browser again. That would be the biggest benefit.

Comment: Yes, with output cache my homepage is always get from client cache, after first hit. The server just return a 304 code

Comment: What I'm saying is to set the expiry headers in the future so the browser doesn't even send the request to get 304 back